# Upgrading from a previous version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, version

I need to upgrade the LocalDB of VS 2019 from 2016 to 2019 version because I work with SQL Server and it's important versions of both products to be compatible. I've gotten the error where there's notation as if:

> ...cannot be opened because it is version 904. This server supports version 852 and earlier...

As it seamed, I've found the solution. I had just upgrade this SQL Server with aid of installer. But when I go to the link "Upgrade from a previous version of SQL Server", I must choose the correct directory. And as you can guess, I don't know the correct directory.

What's your advice? May I reinstall the program? Thank you for attention.

Comment: Open Visual Studio Installer from Start Menu. Remove LocalDB component. Then run LocalDB 2019 standalone installer

Comment: Shall I install LocalDB 2019 into any directory or the directory matters?

Comment: Just use the default

Comment: The problem isn't solved. I don't know the correct directory to upgrade this version of SQL for VS 2019.

Comment: It needs the choice of the correct directory again.