# How to choose the correct directory for updating SQL Server LocalDB for VS 2019?

Tags: sql-server, directory, visual-studio-2019, localdb, ssms-18

I have an objective to connect my database that is created with SQL Server Management Studio 18 to my Win Forms program with help of Visual Studio 2019. But I cannot get the correct connection because of some error. The error:

> ... cannot be opened because it is version 904. This server supports version 852 and earlier...

I know that's not some sort of disaster and I can just update Visual Studio 2019’s LocalDB to SQL 2019, but I'm not sure how to do that. I don't know the directory of Visual Studio 2019’s LocalDB. I should go to the center of SQL Server installation and opt "Upgrade from a previous version of SQL Server". But also I should choose the directory. Just I know I didn't change the directory of any of the listed programs. These directories are set by default. And I have no idea where I can get the information about this one.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68723449/upgrading-from-a-previous-version-of-sql-server)?

Comment: Yes. That's a duplicate

Comment: But how can I solve this one?